# trying to get a timestamp inputed upon a click of the button

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, timestamp

this is the coding that i am working on and cannot figure out how to have a button just input a basic non-counting timestamp from the current time. Can anyone help me fix my problem please. all i am trying to do is have a time stamp be placed in a box next to the get time button...

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">



function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}


window.onclick = "getTimeStamp" ;


</script>

</head>

<body>
<td>
<button type="button" onclick="form"><form name="getTimeStamp">

 <input type=text" name="field" value="" size="11">
</form>Get Time</button></td>




<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a form in a button, the button must be in the form. You need to write the returned value where you can see it.

```
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="this.form.timeField.value=getTimeStamp()">Get time stamp</button>
  <input type="text" name="timeField" size="11">
</form>
```

Don't give any element in the document a name or ID that is the same as a global variable (e.g. a form and function called "getTimeStamp").

Remove:

```
window.onclick = "getTimeStamp";
```

it assigns the string "getTimeStamp" to the *onclick* property of *window*, and does nothing useful.

You can also remove:

```
language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
```

The first was only necessary in very particular circumstances a long time ago, the second was never really necessary other than being required in HTML 4. It's not required any longer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have some basic errors.

This is working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}
function setTime() {
    document.getElementById('field').value = getTimeStamp();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="setTime()">

<input id="field" type="text" name="field" value="" size="11" />
<button type="button" onclick="setTime();">Get Time</button>

</body>
</html>
```

1. you cannot nest `form` under `button`; in this case you can skip the `form`
2. you need somehow identify the `input` which you want to set the time
3. you can reach this `input` by setting it the ID
4. in my example I am using `onload` event in `body` element to set the initial timestamp

If you have any questions you can ask them.